# How to get information from an already populated form

Tags: php, mysql

I am  trying to update a database record using a submit button, however the form that information is being taken from has itself been populated by another submit button.

The PHP is below:

```
if (isset($_POST['edit']))
{
    $editUser = User::locate($_POST['userSelect']);
    $setCompany = Company::findCompany();
    $exCompanyId = $editUser->user_company_id;
    $isAdmin = $editUser->user_admin;
    $eUserFirstname = $editUser->user_firstname;
    $eUserLastname = $editUser->user_lastname;
    $eUserUsername = $editUser->user_username;
    $eUserEmail = $editUser->user_email;
    $eUserCompany = $editUser->user_company;
    $adminArray = array("Yes","No");
    if ($exCompanyId > NULL)
    {
        $exCompany = Company::locateId($exCompanyId);
        $companyValue = $exCompany->company_name;
    }
    else
    {
        $companyValue = "";
    }
    if ($isAdmin > 0)
    {
        $userAdmin = $adminArray[0];

    }
    else
    {
        $userAdmin = $adminArray[1];
    }
}
if (isset($_POST['confirm']))
{
    $updateUserRecord = User::locate($eUserUsername);
    $newCompanyValue = $_POST['setCompany'];
    $isAdmin = $_POST['userAdmin'];
    $newCompany = Company::locate($newCompanyValue);
    $companyId = $newCompany->company_id;

    $updateUserRecord->user_company_id = $companyId;
    $updateUserRecord->user_admin = $isAdmin;

    $editUser->updateUserAdmin();

    $message = "You have successfully updated the user account";
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
}
```

The HTML code is below:

```
<form action="" method="post">
            <p>
                <label>First Name:</label>
                <label><?php echo $eUserFirstname ?></label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Last Name:</label>
                <label><?php echo $eUserLastname ?></label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Username:</label>
                <label><?php echo $eUserUsername ?></label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Email Address:</label>
                <label><?php echo $eUserEmail ?></label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>User Company:</label>
                <label><?php echo $eUserCompany ?></label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Set Company:</label>
                <select name="setCompany">
                    <option><?php echo $companyValue ?></option>
                    <?php
                    foreach ($setCompany as $srow)
                    {
                        ?>
                        <option id="<?=
                        $srow->company_id
                        ?>">
                            <?=
                            $srow->company_name
                            ?>
                        </option>
                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Administrator:</label>
                <select name="userAdmin">
                    <option><?php echo $userAdmin ?></option>
                    <?php
                    foreach ($adminArray as $arow)
                    {
                        ?>
                        <option>
                            <?=
                            $arow
                            ?>
                        </option>
                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </p>
            <input type="submit" name="cancel" value="Cancel">
            <input type="submit" name="confirm" value="Confirm">
            </br>
        </form>
```

From my investigations so far the variables aren't transferring to the 2nd if statement, and I'm not sure how to make them available to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the first form's submission in hidden input fields alongside your echo statements. For example: `<input type="hidden" name="field_name" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($field); ?>">`

Or, alternatively, update the DB after first form posts.

Comment: if it's hidden how will a user be able to confirm?

Comment: You would still be echoing the contents. Eg: `<label><?php echo $eUserFirstname ?><input type="hidden" name="eFirstName" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($eUserFirstname); ?>"></label>`

Comment: Yhea I see.. the question was directed to the op, `<label>...</label>` Prevents users from changing any values, what if a user get's married lastname need's to change, does not cater that

Comment: Also, instead of hidden, you could just display the contents in textfields so they can edit it if necessary.

Comment: @HalfCrazed I will try this out, thank you. For information, this is just for the administrator to update what parts of the website the user can access, the user will be able to edit the other fields themselves if they need to.

Comment: *For information, this is just for the administrator to update what parts of the website the user can access* @NickFallows IN FUTURE gives as much details on the question itself

Comment: Ahh, gotcha. That was unclear. You should probably, instead, use a USER ID as a reference to update attributes on an existing user, instead of other columns.